# Dar de alta micro servicio de azure de forma automática

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, azure

Tengo una arquitectura de 2 microservicios A y B.
Se me ocurrió que A maneje instancias de micrsoervicios de B, con esto quiero decir que cuando se utilicen los servicios de A éste cree una instancia de B.

A tiene una api rest, una capa lógica, una capa de acceso a datos y una base de datos. B tiene los mismos subsitemas, pero independientes a A.

Pensaba desarrollar A como una web app con una Web Api para poder hacer la comunicación y de la misma forma B.

¿Hay alguna forma de que se pueda hacer por código todo el despliegue de B?

Se debe poder hacer pública una nueva instancia de B con todos sus componentes nuevos, Web API de B, lógica y capa de datos y además que consuma otra base de datos si es posible otro SQL Azure.

Comment: Has probado usar el servicio de Automatización de Azure? https://azure.microsoft.com/es-es/services/automation/

Answer (score 1):

Si la idea es usar una arquitectura de microservicios existen dos alternativas

**Azure Container Service**

En concreto seria implementar Docker

[Servicio de contenedores de Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/es-es/services/container-service/)

**Azure Functions**

[Información general sobre Funciones de Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/es-es/documentation/articles/functions-overview/)

en el articulo comenta

> Funciones de Azure es una excelente solución para procesar datos e integrar sistemas, trabajar con Internet de las cosas (IoT) y generar API simples y microservicios

---

Con estas opciones podrias realizar deploy rapidos de funcionalidad concreta de codigo, en donde solo subas la funcionalidad aistalada de ese microservicios sin afectar al resto

A donde apunto es que no uses servicio web simples si la arquitectura es de microservicios

Comment: Gracias por los consejos. Saludos